# Animate image from array with animation style

Tags: uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I have 3 images in my array for this sample code it just animate without any style .I want to animate like fade in fade out style.

```
NSArray *imarray =  [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/lady1_open.png",  path]],
  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/lady1_open2.png", path]],
  [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/lady1_open3.png", path]],
  nil];

bingo_girl.animationImages=imarray;
bingo_girl.animationDuration=5;
bingo_girl.animationRepeatCount=0;
[bingo_girl.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[bingo_girl startAnimating];
```

Comment: Where does `transition` come from? How is it created, etc.?

Comment: This transition is just change the frame by frame but not like what i want.

Answer (score -1):

You may animate images with transition manually for example using this category

```
@implementation UIImageView (AnimateTransition)
 - (void) assignImage:(UIImage *)image withTransition:(NSString *)withTransition withDirection:(NSString *)withDirection{

if(image == nil)
{
    [self setImage:nil];
    return;
}

if ([UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image) isEqualToData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)])        {
    return;
}

CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.duration = 0.2;
animation.type = withDirection;
animation.subtype = withDirection;
[[self layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"imageFade"];
[self setImage:image];
}

@end
```

Comment: - (void) assignImage:(UIImage *)image withTransition:(NSString *)withTransition withDirection:(NSString *)withDirection;Seem like this method didnt work with array.Or what i do wrong

Comment: It is a method for one image. Just iterate through images with timer and apply this method for changing image in UIImageView